# Switch tab at specific time interval in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I want to switch the routes(tabs) at specific time interval. 
At every 15 secs routes should be switch.

```
angular.module('InternalDashboardAPP').config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'Home/PendingRotator',
    controller: 'PendingRotatorController'
})
.when('/PendingsUncheck', {
    templateUrl: 'Home/PendingsUncheck',
    controller: 'PendingsUncheckController'
})
.when('/CasePendingsUncheck', {
    templateUrl: 'Home/CasePendingsUncheck',
    controller: 'CasePendingsUncheckController'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});

}])
```

here is my index.cshtml

```
<div ng-app="InternalDashboardAPP" ng-controller="HomeController">
<div id="mainContentContainer">

    <ul class="navigationStyle">
        <li class="linkDashboard"><a href="#/">Keyword Pendings</a></li>
        <li  class="linkActive"><a href="#/PendingsUncheck">Pendings unchecked per hour</a></li>
        <li  class="linkActive"><a href="#/CasePendingsUncheck">Case Pendings unchecked per hour</a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to SWITCH TAB @PankajParkar

Answer (score 0):

In a `.run` inject `$interval` and just continuously cycle through each `$route`

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple...

Get your defined routes to an array.

```
var defined_routes = ["/", "foo", "bar"];

for(var i in defined_routes){

  setInterval(function(){

    $location.path(defined_routes[i]);

  }, 15000);

}
```

Fund a method. `$route.routes`

Inject $route and there is a property in `$route` object called `$route.routes`. It's return all defined routes. And change above method

Angular doc says

**routes**

> Object with all route configuration Objects as its properties.

Comment: I am beginner in angular. Kindly elaborate in detail. I have created the above function and called it from init(). @underscore